# Is there a way to get list of queries that executed on Google Datastore over a period of time... like last two days?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am trying to get info on the queries that were executed on Google Datastore. Is there a way to get list of queries that executed on Google Datastore over a period of time... like last two days?

Answer (score 0):

Datastore query execution history isn't logged to [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/logging/) automatically, only [these](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-datastore) ones are.

You need to implement your own custom logging using [Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries).